# Will MetaMask support EIP-1559?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

The London Upgrade is live and was wondering if MetaMask Will support EIP-1559?

Thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MetaMask will support EIP-1559 on August 5, 2021.

Source: https://metamask.io/1559.html